# remove form control dynamically in angular 2 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

Try to remove a control that I add to a form

I have tried `this.*FormArray*.splice` but it doesn't compile. Saying that `FormArray has no method splice`. Then I tried `removeAt()` but then when I run the code the error says, `removeAt is not a method`. One compile time fails, the next runtime fails.

I want to remove a control from an array of controls.

Comment: If you want to remove a specific **FormGroup** from your `FormArray`, you can do it like this (specifying the index): `removeAt(<index>)`. If you want to remove a specific control from each FormGroup, you'll have to loop through the FormArray.

Comment: @developer033 `[FormGroup, FormGroup] - what is the removeAt being called on?

Comment: [**See this tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2). It has a PLUNKER that you can see how to remove as I'm saying.

Comment: This should be written as answer: this.*FormArray*.removeAt(<index>)

Comment: I am getting the ERROR 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOn' of null' on form submit after dynamically removing the form control. Has anyone resolved this issue ? @Phil

Answer (score 0):

`removeAt()` is a method on the FormArray namespace, but not a ES5-7 method.

`(<FormArray>items).removeAt(idx)` forced the array to become a `Typescript FormArray` object which opened up the methods.